# Tsibble year week function returns in undesired behaviour

Tags: r, date, lubridate, tsibble

I try to convert a date column with missing values into year-week format with `tsibble`. Doing this returns either in parsing failures or numeric outcomes.

The final output shall look like this: 2020 W1, 2020 W6.

Is there a way to solve this using the `tsibble` package? Strangly, the `yearmonth` function of this package works also with NA and empty values.

```
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)

x <- c("2020-01-01", "", "2020-02-06")

yearweek(x)
# Output: fails

ifelse(x == "", "", yearweek(ymd(x)))
# Output: "18260" "" "18295"

# Desired Output: "2020 W1", "", "2020 W6".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in base R :

```
format(as.Date(x), "%Y W%V")
#[1] "2020 W01" NA         "2020 W06"
```

---

When you use this in `yearweek` from `tsibble` it returns an error

```
library(tsibble)
yearweek(as.Date(x))
```

> Error in yrs[mth_wk == "12_01"] <- yr[mth_wk == "12_01"] + 1 : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Since `yearweek` function returns output of class `"yearweek" "Date"` it doesn't allow `NA` values in it or empty values (`""`) because they are not of the class `"yearweek" "Date"`. A hack is to change the values to character instead.

```
x1 <- as.Date(x)
inds <- !is.na(x1)
x2 <- character(length = length(x1))
x2[inds] <- as.character(yearweek(x1[inds]))
x2
#[1] "2020 W01" ""         "2020 W06"
```

Comment: thanks! that indeed solves my issue, completly overlook the base R solution. Any idea why this `yearweek` function does not work as expected?

Comment: @rkraft I added some explanation and a way to make `yearweek` work.